# How can I configure Maven (command line) and the IDE to build in different folders?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide, maven-2

I'm often switching between my IDE (running just the unit tests for the code which I'm working on) and the command line (running all unit tests).

This causes problems: Sometimes, `mvn clean` fails because the IDE is building the code. Or I get weird errors in the IDE about missing classes because the IDE is reading files which Maven has modified.

Also, I can't continue working in the IDE why Maven builds in the background.

How can I configure my IDE or Maven to use different build folders?

Answer (score 1):

Use profiles and this code in your (parent) POM:

```
<project>
  ...

  <build>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/${target.dir}/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/${target.dir}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
  </build>

  <properties>
    <target.dir>target</target.dir>
  </properties>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>ide-folders</id>
      <properties>
        <target.dir>target-ide</target.dir>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ...
```

Configure the project in your IDE to enable the profile `target-ide` when building. Now Maven and the IDE use different folders.

Alternatively, you could enable this profile in your `settings.xml` and make the folder `target-ide` the default. This way, you wouldn't have to modify the settings of many projects in your IDE. It would even work on your CI build server (it would build into `target-ide` but who cares? And if you cared enough, you can enable the profile there as well).

Note: This is based on a blog-post on jroller.com which is down. The Internet Archive has a copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20150527111413/http://www.jroller.com/eu/entry/configuring_separate_maven_output_folders